# android smack subscribe user not working

Tags: android

i am using below code to send friend request to any user its working fine but i am not able to find the connected user from roster list.

Now i want to know how could i identify new requested friend in roster list.

```
Roster roster = XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection.getRoster();
roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
try {
    if(!_userName.contains("@"))
        _userName=_userName+"@204.93.197.136";

    Presence response = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
    response.setTo(_userName);
    XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection.sendPacket(response);

    //roster.createEntry(_userName, _nickName, my_friends[]);
    //addBuddy(_userName, _nickName, Friends);
} catch (Exception e) {
    _progDailog.dismiss();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been trying to resolve a similar issue where the Roster List does not updated on accepting a friend's request.
Steps followed :-

1. Sent a friend request using Presence type as **subscribe**
2. At the other end, while accepting the friend's request, a **subscribed** presence type is sent
3. On receiving the subscribed Presence packet, another **subscribed** packet is sent back.

The server's roster list gets updated immediately by Subscription type as Both but the roster entries are not.
Also, the roster's subscription Mode is set to **manual** and it also has a PacketListener attached to it.

Please can you provide some help by contributing your solution to this problem? It would be of great help.

Thanks and Regards,
Vaidehi

Comment: This ways is working but some time I am not getting updated Roster. I am also using PacketLister for identify all type of notification. Can you tell me some specific about this sentence...... it also has a PacketListener attached to it...... how i can use packet listener for subscribe and subscribed

Comment: That was my question too... Were you able to get the updated roster lists by using the Packet Listener?